# Creating Lists of Dictionaries with N dicts per list

Tags: python, python-3.x

##### Problem

I am dealing with a response object and I am trying to massage it into something which could be easily consumed by a Typescript frontend.

##### The object:

```py
r_obj = [
    {
        'custom_fields': [
            {'id': 360018501198, 'value': '5678'},
            {'id': 360023508598, 'value': 'Jim'},
            {'id': 1900000084913, 'value': '2021-09-03'}
         ]
    },
    {
        'custom_fields': [
            {'id': 360018501198, 'value': '1234'},
            {'id': 360023508598, 'value': 'Bob'},
            {'id': 1900000084913, 'value': '2021-09-03'}
        ]
    }
]
```

##### Desired Structure

```
[
  {
    "order_id": '5678',
    "name": "Jim",
    "date": '2021-09-03'
  },
  {
    "order_id": '1234',
    "name": "Bob",
    "date": '2021-09-03'
  },

]
```

So `id` values in the `custom_field` payload are known and I want to map them to enum representation and with the hope that the output payload contain saner k,v pairs.

##### The Code

I have only managed to do the mapping of the enum values.

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":

    class FieldEnum(enum.IntEnum):
        ORDER_ID = 360018501198
        DATE = 1900000084913
        NAME = 360023508598

    r_obj = [
        {
            'custom_fields': [
                {'id': 360018501198, 'value': '5678'},
                {'id': 360023508598, 'value': 'Jim'},
                {'id': 1900000084913, 'value': '2021-09-03'}
            ]
        },
        {
            'custom_fields': [
                {'id': 360018501198, 'value': '1234'},
                {'id': 360023508598, 'value': 'Bob'},
                {'id': 1900000084913, 'value': '2021-09-03'}
            ]
        }
    ]
    for row in r_obj:
        for field in row['custom_fields']:
            if field['id']:
                field['id'] = FieldEnum(field['id']).name.lower()
            
            print(field)
```

#### Code Output

```
{'id': 'order_id', 'value': '5678'}
{'id': 'name', 'value': 'Jim'}
{'id': 'date', 'value': '2021-09-03'}
{'id': 'order_id', 'value': '1234'}
{'id': 'name', 'value': 'Bob'}
{'id': 'date', 'value': '2021-09-03'}
```

I am struggling with how best to group(?) each set of 3 dicts into its own list structure.

## EDIT

As per @balderman, I have altered to this:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":

    class FieldEnum(enum.IntEnum):
        ORDER_ID = 360018501198
        DATE = 1900000084913
        NAME = 360023508598

    r_obj = [
        {
            'custom_fields': [
                {'id': 360018501198, 'value': '5678'},
                {'id': 360023508598, 'value': 'Jim'},
                {'id': 1900000084913, 'value': '2021-09-03'}
            ]
        },
        {
            'custom_fields': [
                {'id': 360018501198, 'value': '1234'},
                {'id': 360023508598, 'value': 'Bob'},
                {'id': 1900000084913, 'value': '2021-09-03'}
            ]
        }
    ]

    out = list()
    for entry in r_obj:
        out.append({})
        for f in entry['custom_fields']:
            out[-1][FieldEnum(f['id']).name.lower()] = f['value']
    print(out)
```

#### Code Output

```
[
  {
    'order_id': '5678', 
    'name': 'Jim', 
    'date': '2021-09-03'
  }, 
  {
    'order_id': '1234', 
    'name': 'Bob', 
    'date': '2021-09-03'
  }
]
```

Which is the desired output.

I was wondering if there is another way syntactically to achieve the same output?

Comment: As in on the `for row in r_obj:` block just append `row` to a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I would do it with a `list comprehension` to make it one-liner

#### code:

```
import enum
class FieldEnum(enum.IntEnum):
    ORDER_ID = 360018501198
    DATE = 1900000084913
    NAME = 360023508598

r_obj = [
    {
        'custom_fields': [
            {'id': 360018501198, 'value': '5678'},
            {'id': 360023508598, 'value': 'Jim'},
            {'id': 1900000084913, 'value': '2021-09-03'}
        ]
    },
    {
        'custom_fields': [
            {'id': 360018501198, 'value': '1234'},
            {'id': 360023508598, 'value': 'Bob'},
            {'id': 1900000084913, 'value': '2021-09-03'}
        ]
    }
]

print([{FieldEnum(f['id']).name.lower():f['value'] for f in entry['custom_fields'] } for entry in r_obj])
```

#### result:

```
[
    {"order_id": "5678", "name": "Jim", "date": "2021-09-03"},
    {"order_id": "1234", "name": "Bob", "date": "2021-09-03"},
]
```

Answer (score 1):

try the below

```
lookup = {360018501198: 'order_id', 360023508598: 'name', 1900000084913: 'date'}

data = [{
    'custom_fields': [
        {'id': 360018501198, 'value': '5678'},
        {'id': 360023508598, 'value': 'Jim'},
        {'id': 1900000084913, 'value': '2021-09-03'}
    ]
},
    {
        'custom_fields': [
            {'id': 360018501198, 'value': '1234'},
            {'id': 360023508598, 'value': 'Bob'},
            {'id': 1900000084913, 'value': '2021-09-03'}
        ]
    }
]

out = list()
for entry in data:
    out.append({})
    for f in entry['custom_fields']:
        out[-1][lookup[f['id']]] = f['value']
print(out)
```

output

```
[{'order_id': '5678', 'name': 'Jim', 'date': '2021-09-03'}, {'order_id': '1234', 'name': 'Bob', 'date': '2021-09-03'}]
```

Comment: Thank you, I have edited my question because I am interested to see if it could be done another way. Will mark this as the answer if no one wants to contribute.